RTSP Url not playing using media kit in Flutter
Trying to open an RTSP stream on my flutter app using media kit. Have used the below code. The video stream is not opening - the screen is blank.
Below is the log ad code snippet - any guidance will be really helpful.
> [log] Inside init state of RTSP Player
> I/media_kit( 7765): flutterJNIAPIAvailable = true
> I/media_kit( 7765): com.alexmercerind.media_kit_video.VideoOutput: id = 0
> I/flutter ( 7765): {id: 0}
> I/flutter ( 7765): media_kit: wakelock: _count = 1
> I/media_kit( 7765): com.alexmercerind.media_kit_video.VideoOutputManager.createSurface: 3097775024
> I/flutter ( 7765): {wid: 6442}
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/ra
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/ra
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/alac
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/alac
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/ape
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/ape
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/adpcm
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-adpcm
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/pcm
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/pcm
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/dsd
> W/AudioCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime audio/dsd
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/rv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/rv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv2
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv2
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/divx3
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/divx3
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/flv1
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-flv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/flv1
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-flv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/mjpeg
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-motion-jpeg
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/mjpeg
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-motion-jpeg
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
> W/VideoCapabilities( 7765): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv
> W/AString ( 7765): ctor got NULL, using empty string instead
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): CreateByComponentName,componentName is:c2.mtk.avc.decoder
> I/CCodecBufferChannel( 7765): Constructor 0x9ab44400
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): allocate(c2.mtk.avc.decoder)
> I/Codec2Client( 7765): Available Codec2 services: "default" "software" "vivocodec"
> I/CCodec  ( 7765): setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
> I/CCodec  ( 7765): Created component [c2.mtk.avc.decoder]
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): read media type: video/avc
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
> D/ReflectedParamUpdater( 7765): ignored struct field coded.color-format.locations
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): ignoring local param raw.size (0xd2001800) as it is already supported
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): ignoring local param raw.crop (0xd2001801) as it is already supported
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): ignoring local param default.color (0x5200180b) as it is already supported
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): ignoring local param raw.hdr-static-info (0xd200180a) as it is already supported
> I/CCodecConfig( 7765): query failed after returning 17 values (BAD_INDEX)
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): c2 config diff is Dict {
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::i32 algo.priority.value = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::float algo.rate.value = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::float coded.frame-rate.value = 30
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 20494
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 20481
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.matrix = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.primaries = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.range = 2
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.transfer = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 default.color.matrix = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 default.color.primaries = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 default.color.range = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 default.color.transfer = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 2097152
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 input.delay.value = 4
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   string input.media-type.value = "video/avc"
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 output.delay.value = 12
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   string output.media-type.value = "video/raw"
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 2
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.crop.height = 239
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.crop.left = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.crop.top = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.crop.width = 319
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::float raw.hdr-static-info.mastering.blue.x = 0
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::float raw.hdr-s
> W/ColorUtils( 7765): expected specified color aspects (2:0:0:0)
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): mInitName[c2.mtk.avc.decoder], mMediacodec[0x61af2800], mCodec[0x7e7b6900], mBufferChannel[0x9ab44400]
> W/libc    ( 7765): Access denied finding property "vendor.vivo.debug.PqSetting.enable"
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): flushMediametrics
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): Client requested ByteBuffer mode decoder w/o color format set: using default planar color format
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): no c2 equivalents for csd-1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): no c2 equivalents for flags
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 1080
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 1920
> W/ColorUtils( 7765): expected specified color aspects (2:0:0:0)
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   string mime = "video/avc"
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t width = 1920
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t profile = 65536
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t priority = -1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t frame-rate = 30
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t height = 1080
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t level = 16384
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t max-input-size = 2097152
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   Rect crop(0, 0, 318, 238)
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): }
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): setup formats output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t android._color-format = 2135033992
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t android._video-scaling = 1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t sar-width = 1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-standard = 0
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-range = 2
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-transfer = 0
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t android._dataspace = 268435456
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t width = 1920
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t rotation-degrees = 0
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t sar-height = 1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t max-width = 320
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t max-height = 240
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t priority = -1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   string mime = "video/raw"
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   Rect crop(0, 0, 318, 238)
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   Buffer hdr-static-info = {
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):     00000000:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):     00000010:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00                       .........
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   }
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t frame-rate = 30
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t height = 1080
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-format = 19
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): }
> c    ( 7765): Access denied finding property "vendor.vivo.debug.PqSetting.enable"
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): flushMediametrics
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): Client requested ByteBuffer mode decoder w/o color format set: using default planar color format
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): no c2 equivalents for csd-1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): no c2 equivalents for flags
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.size.height = 1080
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.size.width = 1920
> W/ColorUtils( 7765): expected specified color aspects (2:0:0:0)
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): setup formats input: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   string mime = "video/avc"
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t width = 1920
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t profile = 65536
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t priority = -1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t frame-rate = 30
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t height = 1080
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t level = 16384
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t max-input-size = 2097152
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   Rect crop(0, 0, 318, 238)
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): }
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): setup formats output: AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t android._color-format = 2135033992
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t android._video-scaling = 1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t sar-width = 1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-standard = 0
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-range = 2
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-transfer = 0
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t android._dataspace = 268435456
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t width = 1920
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t rotation-degrees = 0
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t sar-height = 1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t max-width = 320
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t max-height = 240
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t priority = -1
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   string mime = "video/raw"
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   Rect crop(0, 0, 318, 238)
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   Buffer hdr-static-info = {
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):     00000000:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):     00000010:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00                       .........
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   }
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t frame-rate = 30
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t height = 1080
> D/CCodec  ( 7765):   int32_t color-format = 19
> D/CCodec  ( 7765): }
> I/CCodecConfig( 7765): query failed after returning 17 values (BAD_INDEX)
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.max-size.height = 1080
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.max-size.width = 1920
> W/ColorUtils( 7765): expected specified color aspects (2:0:0:0)
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
> D/CCodecBufferChannel( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder#360] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 20 - OK (0)
> D/CCodecBufferChannel( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder#360] Configured output block pool ids 1 => OK
> D/CCodecBufferChannel( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder#360] Configured output usage [0x1]
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.color.matrix = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.primaries = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.range = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.color.transfer = 3
> D/CCodecBufferChannel( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder#360] Ignoring stale input buffer done callback: last flush index = 0, frameIndex = 0
> D/Codec2-OutputBufferQueue( 7765): set max dequeue count 19 from update
> E/IMGSRV  ( 7765): :4687: IsTextureConsistent: IMGEGLImage is not consistent
> E/IMGSRV  ( 7765): :4687: IsTextureConsistent: IMGEGLImage is not consistent
> E/IMGSRV  ( 7765): :4687: IsTextureConsistent: IMGEGLImage is not consistent
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder#360:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: at 0us, output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t android._color-format = 2135033992
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t android._video-scaling = 1
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t sar-width = 1
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t color-standard = 1
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t color-range = 1
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t color-transfer = 3
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t android._dataspace = 146866176
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t width = 1920
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t rotation-degrees = 0
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t sar-height = 1
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t max-width = 1920
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t max-height = 1080
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t priority = -1
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   string mime = "video/raw"
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   Rect crop(0, 0, 318, 238)
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   Buffer hdr-static-info = {
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):     00000000:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):     00000010:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00                       .........
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   }
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t frame-rate = 30
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t height = 1080
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765):   int32_t color-format = 19
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765): }
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5c780000, buffer=0x9aae3c90
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x9aae3c90
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5be3e000, buffer=0x5cf2cbc0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cbc0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5bc3e000, buffer=0x5cf2cd80
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cd80
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b83e000, buffer=0x5cf2cdf0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cdf0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b63e000, buffer=0x5cf2ce28
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2ce28
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b43e000, buffer=0x5cf2ce60
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2ce60
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b23e000, buffer=0x5cf2ce98
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2ce98
> I/CCodecConfig( 7765): query failed after returning 17 values (BAD_INDEX)
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765): c2 config diff is   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.matrix = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.primaries = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.range = 1
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 coded.vui.color.transfer = 3
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.crop.height = 1080
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.crop.width = 1920
> D/CCodecConfig( 7765):   c2::u32 raw.pixel-format.value = 2130706433
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
> 
> I/CCodecConfig( 7765): query failed after returning 17 values (BAD_INDEX)
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5c780000, buffer=0x9aae3c90
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x9aae3c90
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5be3e000, buffer=0x5cf2cbc0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cbc0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5bc3e000, buffer=0x5cf2cd80
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cd80
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5ba3e000, buffer=0x5cf2cdb8
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cdb8
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b83e000, buffer=0x5cf2cdf0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2cdf0
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b63e000, buffer=0x5cf2ce28
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2ce28
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b43e000, buffer=0x5cf2ce60
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2ce60
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): MediaCodecBuffer:0x5b23e000, buffer=0x5cf2ce98
> D/MediaCodec( 7765): returnBuffersToCodecOnPort():enter else:info->mData=0x5cf2ce98
> D/CCodecBuffers( 7765): [c2.mtk.avc.decoder#360:1D-Input.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 7
> I/CCodecConfig( 7765): query failed after returning 17 values (BAD_INDEX)
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
> W/Codec2Client( 7765): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
> I/flutter ( 7765): media_kit: wakelock: _count = 0
> I/media_kit( 7765): VideoOutput.WaitUntilFirstFrameRenderedNotify = 3082563504
> I/flutter ( 7765): VideoOutput.WaitUntilFirstFrameRenderedNotify
> I/flutter ( 7765): {handle: 3082563504}
> I/flutter ( 7765): 3082563504
> D/PipelineWatcher( 7765): DEBUG: elapsed 0 / 16
> D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7765): bufferpool2 0x79234fd8 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 0/8 (recycle/alloc) - 8/17 (fetch/transfer)
> D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7765): evictor expired: 1, evicted: 1
> D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7765): evictor expired: 2, evicted: 0
> D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7765): bufferpool2 0xa229e518 : 8(16777216 size) total buffers - 8(16777216 size) used buffers - 0/8 (recycle/alloc) - 3/3 (fetch/transfer)
> D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7765): evictor expired: 1, evicted: 1
> I/ster_client.ap( 7765): Thread[6,tid=7773,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xba905400,peer=0x134000f0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 10
> I/ster_client.ap( 7765):
> I/ster_client.ap( 7765): SIGUSR1 forcing GC (no HPROF) and profile save
> I/ster_client.ap( 7765): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 45122(1508KB) AllocSpace objects, 66(2376KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4210KB/8421KB, paused 403us,115us total 142.388ms
> Application finished.
> 
> Exited (-1).

Was expecting the RTSP stream running.
The stream is running on VLC app on same phone. Camera permission is enabled as well.
Issue seems to be on Flutter's media kit played. Any guidance will be helpful
Version of packages used
media_kit: ^1.1.11                             # Primary package.

media_kit_video: ^1.2.5                        # For video rendering.

media_kit_libs_video: ^1.0.5   

Summary of flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version
10.0.22631.4602], locale en-IN)
Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or
higher)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
version 34.0.0)
Chrome - develop for the web
Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.4)
Android Studio (version 2022.3)
VS Code (version 1.96.1)
Connected device (4 available)
Network resources
Code
class _HLSPlayerScreenState extends State<HLSPlayerScreen> {
  late final _player = Player();
  late final _controller = VideoController(_player);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    log('Inside init state of HLS Player');

    String url = Uri.encodeFull("rtsp://username:password@192.xxx.x.xx:554/Streaming/Channels/101");

    _player.open(
      Media(url),
      play: true, // Automatically play the video
    );
  }
}


Open a gh issue for the flutter libary
